# Mechanize import "ModuleNoFoundError"

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm on ParrotOS and trying to code a script that brings up a people lookup website (like intelius) and based on information you put, it prints the results and if you see your information, you can remove it.
But when I try to import Mechanize it gives me this error:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mechanize' "

Comment: can you share your file structure?

Comment: @JoseAngelSanchez What do you mean?

Comment: from what folder is it running? I just want to see your tree

Comment: @JoseAngelSanchez What would I type to show that? i'm new to linux :p

Comment: ```tree``` if you get an error, ```sudo apt-get install tree``` (in ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you haven't installed mechanize

Try :
`pip install mechanize`

Or

`pip3 install mechanize` for python 3